# How setup a shopify public app with Vue or Nuxtjs?

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, shopify-app, shopify-template

I want to build a shopify public app using Nuxtjs or Vuejs, but I am having a hard time figuring out how to bridge shopify with the application. Does anyone know if there is a guide available for this. I have scoured the internet and have gotten know where.